# How can I know if the message sent by websocket success or not

Tags: websocket, cowboy

I developed a chat server using websocket in cowboy, but I want to know if the message sent by server to client success.How can I know?

Comment: You should come back and choose an answer for your question

Answer (score 45):

Websocket is a rather thin abstraction layer on top of a conventional TCP socket. After the initial handshake the difference is minimal. So, the question is: how do I know if a data chunk was received by the remote peer? The short answer: only if the peer acknowledges it explicitly by the means of application-level protocol. Remote client will send TCP ACK packets for every data packet you will send it, but this fact is well hidden from the application for good reasons. Receiving ACK packet only means that remote TCP stack has dealt with it, but says nothing about how (and if) the client application has processed it.

Add a special "acknowledge receive" message type to your chat protocol. Include a monotonically increasing sequence number in all of your outgoing messages, and include the SN of the received message in the ACK message to know exactly how much data the client has already processed.